# How to calculate GPA for each group in Crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have to develop a report which will show the student's current semester Grade, Credit for each course and student details. And Total GPA for each student on that semester.
So for this, I have created Group depending on Student ID. So now the report Shows Ok but I have to calculate the GPA for each student ID which is each group in Crystal Report. The formula for GPA is:

```
 (grade point * credit)/Sum(Credit)
```

I am not so sure how I can apply this formula in each group footer.

Mentioned: I am using Crystal Report 10, VB.NET, Mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
//{@GPA}
Sum({table.grade_point},{table.student_id}) / Sum({table.credit},{table.student_id}) / Sum({table.credit},{table.student_id})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I tried this formula but it is not giving the correct result..any other idea???

Answer (score 0):

Put each student as a group then in the details you can put the credits and grade. quick outline:

```
//Group1 header 
{t.student} 
//detail 
{b.course_num}  {b.credit} {b.grade} {@grade} 
//group1 footer 
{?credit_hours}  {@GPA}

//{@grade} place in details
  case {b.grade}
  when A  then 4.00
  when A- then 3.70
  when B+ then 3.33
  when B  then 3.00
  when B- then 2.70
  when C+ then 2.30
  when C  then 2.00
  when C- then 1.70
  when D+ then 1.30
  when D  then 1.00
  when D- then 0.70
  else 0

//{@grade_pt} place in details
  {@grade} * {t.credit}

//{@GPA} place in group footer, and create running totals
  ({?credit_hours}*{?grade})/{?credit_hours}
```